# Реализация общения Slave и Master по i2C для arm используя LUFA

Tags: arm

В качестве лабы в универе задали реализацию общения Slave и Master по I2C для arm. После мучительной пытки гугл всё же согласился поделиться информацией и выдал инфу о библиотеке шаблонов LUFA. Там очень подробно описано в каждом примере, что и как делается, но реализация имеется только для slave-а и master-а в отдельности. Подскажите, как полностью импортировать один проект в другой вместе с зависимостями.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате, какие технологии используете и т. д.